# ggplot: add multiline text annotation outside of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, textbox

I want to add a textbox of 10 separate, stacked lines outside of my plot area in `ggplot`. My text is: `t = c("a=1", "b=2", "c=3", ... , "j=10")` but these labels are independent of the `data.frame` that I made my original `ggplot`. How can I add 10 lines outside of the plot area?

For example, I want to add a textbox around my vector `t` on the right of the following plot:

```
df = data.frame(y=rnorm(300), test=rep(c(1,2,3),each=100))
t = c("a=1", "b=2", "c=3", "d=4", "e=5", "f=6", "g=7", "h=8", "i=0", "j=10")
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(test), y=y))
p <- p + geom_violin() + geom_jitter(height=0, width=0.1)
p <- p + theme(legend.title=element_blank(), plot.margin=unit(c(0.1, 3, 0.1, 0.1), "cm"))
p
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example so that we can provide code tailored to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p, right = tableGrob(matrix(t,ncol=1),
             theme = ttheme_minimal(padding = unit(c(3,1),"line"))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `geom_text` layer using the label values in `t` in order to get the labels printed as a legend. But we set `alpha=0` in `geom_text` so that these labels won't be included in the plot, and we use `legend.key=element_blank()` and `override.aes(list(size=0))` to get the "legend" labels (the `t` values) printed without the meaningless legend key.

```
p + 
  geom_text(data = data.frame(t, test=NA, y=NA), aes(label=t, colour=t), alpha=0, x=1, y=1) +
  theme(legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.margin=margin(l=-10)) +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=0)))
```

[image]

Comment: When I tried saving, I was getting the following error: `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): label, colour`

Comment: You need to have the same columns in the `geom_text` data frame as are used for the aesthetics in the main call to ggplot2 (that's what the `test=NA, y=NA` are for). They don't have any purpose in the call to `geom_text` but ggplot expects them to be there, so you need to do something similar with your real data.